# Steam not starting on ubuntu budgie 21.04

Tags: steam, 21.04, budgie

I've installed steam but it's refusing to launch. It shows an update screen and then nothing. I've noticed a couple errors while starting with a terminal but I have no idea what they mean or how to fix them. Here's the log:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 21.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/user37/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Startup - updater built Jul 20 2021 22:25:51
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  44
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/user37/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Checking for update on startup
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Checking for available updates...
[2021-08-26 12:49:28] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1626824053)
[2021-08-26 12:49:29] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1626824053, installed version 1626824053, existing pending version 0
[2021-08-26 12:49:29] Nothing to do
[2021-08-26 12:49:29] Verifying installation...
[2021-08-26 12:49:29] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-08-26 12:49:30] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6655637
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:62738): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steam:62738): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Pocillo-dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:1090: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
/usr/share/themes/Pocillo-dark/gtk-2.0/apps.rc:91: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:62738): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210826124928_1.dmp[62788]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210826124928_1.dmp
/home/user37/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 772: 62738 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by updating my nvidia drivers and rebooting.